# ¿Por qué mi array de sap no reconoce la variable x de vba?

Tags: array, excel, vba, vb, sap

Verán estoy haciendo una función para pasar unos datos de mi excel a sap por medio de vb, pero tengo un problema al momento de querer recorrer unos campos en sap, ya que cuando quiero recorrerlos diatónicamente desde mi ciclo for, la linea de codigo donde trae el campo de sap, no reconoce mi variable x. específicamente aquí ctxtRCTMS-MWERT[1,x].
Al querer comprobar el valor de esa variable, en esa linea de código (corriéndolo con un breakpoint), la variable x no me muestra ningún valor, ni siquiera como si estuviera declarada, pero al momento de comprobarla en la linea de "x=x+1" si me muestra el valor de x. Por ende jamás me recorre la posición de sap.

```
Dim x As Integer
x=0

For j = 15 To 33
         If Worksheets("Excel-SAP").Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subCHARACTERISTICS:SAPLCEI0:1400/tblSAPLCEI0CHARACTER_VALUES/ctxtRCTMS-MWERT[1,x]").Text = Worksheets("Excel-SAP").Cells(i, j).Value
         Else
         End If
         x = x + 1
Next
```

Desconozco si es sap o no acepte esta lógica ya que las posiciones con excel si las trae, y que podría ser, ya que he intentado de diferentes maneras, como poniendo la variable publica y cambiando la sintaxis del array, pero no he tenido éxito, me gustaría saber el porqué no me trae la posición de esa variable.

Les agradecería mucho su apoyo.
Excelente día.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al tenerlo entre comillas VBA lo pasa por alto. Tienes que sacarlo de esa cadena si quieres que lo evalúe. Prueba esto:

```
Dim x As Integer
x=0

For j = 15 To 33
         If Worksheets("Excel-SAP").Cells(i, j).Value <> "" Then
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subCHARACTERISTICS:SAPLCEI0:1400/tblSAPLCEI0CHARACTER_VALUES/ctxtRCTMS-MWERT[1," & x & "]").Text = Worksheets("Excel-SAP").Cells(i, j).Value
         Else
         End If
         x = x + 1
Next
```

Comment: Hermano muchas gracias!! me había percatado de la cadena pero jamás lo supe interpretar y pensar que se tenia que concatenar esa variable.

Muchísimas gracias!!!!!!!